# Notepad++ search and replace words between [ ]

Tags: notepad++

I have a subtitle file with lines like:
**[music in the background] What do you need?**
How can I search and replace **[music in the background]** with nothing?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to remove **all** strings inside square brackets or only when the string is `music in the background`? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1695336/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: all the string inside with strings and words too, so the lines like: [music in the background] What do you need? Will become just: What do you need?
There are random lines with [text inside] that I want removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\[.+?\])`
- Replace with: leave it empty
- Search mode: Regular Expression

Comment: Thank you, it works! It happens that I have in subtitle two lines that does not get affected. like: 00:01:22,737 --> 00:01:26,939
[both speaking in
foreign language]
Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/240jbzl

Comment: See my edits please, it's 90% done :D

Comment: @McAbadBoy Try to find the following: `\[.+\R?.+?\]`

Comment: Works now, thank you!

Comment: @McAbadBoy Please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)